# Menu hambúrguer ocultando quando chama uma nova view Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Tenho uma `View` que está sendo chamada através de um botão do `MenuItem`. Porém dentro dessas `View` contém um outro botão que chama uma nova `View`. Essa nova `View` abre fora do menu hambúrguer, ou seja, ele oculta sozinho.

Preciso que essa nova `View` continue exibindo o menu logo acima como na primeira imagem.

Já usei o `PushModalAsync` e o `PushAsync` mas continua dessa forma.

Como corrigir esse problema de navegação ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que sua 'View` principal (root navigation) deve do tipo `Master-Detail` ela já é desse tipo?.

Comment: Isso, é sim @rubStackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

Usando o MessagingSender no xamarin podemos fazer uma navegação detailpagechanged que mantem o menu em vez de navegação em fila (push e pop) .

```
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page>(this, "DetailPageChanged", (page) =>
        {
            DetailPageChanged(page);
        });

    private void DetailPageChanged(Page page)
    {
        var currentDetailPage = Detail as HoldingPage;
        if (currentDetailPage != null)
        {
            var internalPage = currentDetailPage.CurrentPage as IDisposable;
            if (internalPage != null)
            {
                internalPage.Dispose();
            }
        }

        var holdingPage = new HoldingPage();

        holdingPage.PopAsync();

        holdingPage.PushAsync(page);
        Detail = holdingPage;
    }
```

Você pode criar um Helper e chamar o metodo desta forma :

```
    public static void SendDetailPageChanged(Page detailPage)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<Page>(detailPage, "DetailPageChanged");
    }
```

Comment: é necessário criar o Helper ou pode fazer da primeira forma que vc postou ? E onde exatamente eu crio essa chamada do DetailPageChanged ?

Comment: O Ideal é você criar na sua MenuPage. Entenda o primeiro método é se increvendo para ouvir aquele evento de "DetailPageChanged".
 o segundo método é a mudança de page que você deve realizar.
o terceiro é um helper pra facilitar sua chamada